# LinkedIn API reference

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm trying to pull all the data associated with my companies LinkedIn page, but I can't figure out how to navigate the API... (I already have a bearer token).

I've looked at [these reference fields](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields), but the only `GET` request that gives me anything back is `https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~?format=json` and that gives me my personal profile info, which is not what I want.

If I change "people" to "visitors" for example, I get back:

> "Unknown field {visitors} in resource {Root}"

Is there any documentation on what resources are available in `{Root}` or is there a `GET` request I can send that will show me the available resources?

Note: the only reason I'm using v1 here is because that's the only request I can get to work...

Answer (score 0):

well, the V1 you are using is outdated. it will actually be terminated in March 2019. The reason why V2 is not working. is because V2 requires a LinkedIn partnership. you can request one [here](https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs#).

there are multiple ways you can request company data. for **V1** it is called:

the manage company pages API, click [here for more information](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/company-pages)

for **V2** you should look at organization API, click [here for more information](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/organizations)

**PS**: im not sure if there is a way to get the root information. but hopefully this helps.